# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una variable de una condición en otra?

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy haciendo matrices de 3x3 con Gauss Jordan para resolver primero los tres primeros ceros de la parte posterior de la izquierda. No estoy usando numpy ni ninguna librería, todo es de forma manual.
Al momento de llamar a dos variables para dividir me arroja un error de que una variable no está definida:

**NameError: name 'div2' is not defined**

Aquí está el problema:

```
numero=div2/div4
```

Este es mi código, les advierto que es exageradamente redundante, pero funciona para mi.

```
from fractions import Fraction

print('\nFila 1')
a1=int(input('Valor a: '))
b1=int(input('Valor b: '))
c1=int(input('Valor c: '))#Se definen las matrices
d1=int(input('Valor n: '))

print('\nFila 2')
a2=int(input('Valor a: '))
b2=int(input('Valor b: '))
c2=int(input('Valor c: '))#Se definen las matrices
d2=int(input('Valor n: '))

print('\nFila 3')
a3=int(input('Valor a: '))
b3=int(input('Valor b: '))
c3=int(input('Valor c: '))#Se definen las matrices
d3=int(input('Valor n: '))

print(f'\n {a1}x {b1}y {c1}z | {d1}\n', f'{a2}x {b2}y {c2}z | {d2}\n', f'{a3}x {b3}y {c3}z | {d3}')#Se imprimen de forma estética las matrices con sus incógnitas
print(f'\n {a1} {b1} {c1} | {d1}\n', f'{a2} {b2} {c2} | {d2}\n', f'{a3} {b3} {c3} | {d3}') #Se definen las matrices de forma estética sin incógnitas

if a2 and a3 > a1: #Se declara la primera condición para poner en la fila1 la variable (a1,a2 o a3) más pequeña
    v1=(a1,b1,c1,d1) #Si se cumple la condición 1...
    print(v1) #Se imprime la fila1 que es la más pequeña por la variable a1
    if (a1 != 1) and (b1 != 1) and (c1 != 1) and (d1 != 1): #Si la fila 1 es diferente de 1....
        a,b,c,d=Fraction(a1/a1),Fraction(b1/a1),Fraction(c1/a1),Fraction(d1/a1) #Se divide entre a1
        print(f'\n{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}') #Se imprime la fila ya dividida

        if (a2 < 0): #Terminada la condición anterior se declara una condición donde si el primer valor de la fila2 es diferente de 0...
            opuesto1 = abs(a2) #Se saca su valor absoluto
            multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1=(opuesto1*a1/a1),(opuesto1*b1/a1),(opuesto1*c1/a1),(opuesto1*d1/a1) #La fila 2 se multiplica con la fila 1
            print(multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1) #Se imprime
            resta_fila2_con_fila1=((opuesto1*a1/a1)+a2),((opuesto1*b1/a1)+b2),((opuesto1*c1/a1)+c2),((opuesto1*d1/a1)+d2) #Se resta el producto de la fila1 y fila2 con la fila2
            print(resta_fila2_con_fila1) #Se imprime
            div1=((opuesto1*b1/a1)+b2)   #Se declara la variable dev1 que nos va a servir más adelant para dividir el valor 2 de la fila2 con el valor 2 de la fila 3 y multiplicar ese valor con la fila 3 para obtener el tercer 0.


        else:
            opuesto2 = a2 * (-1)
            multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1=(opuesto2*a1/a1),(opuesto2*b1/a1),(opuesto2*c1/a1),(opuesto2*d1/a1)
            print(multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1)
            resta_fila2_con_fila1=((opuesto2*a1/a1)+a2),((opuesto2*b1/a1)+b2),((opuesto2*c1/a1)+c2),((opuesto2*d1/a1)+d2)
            print(resta_fila2_con_fila1)
            div2=((opuesto2*b1/a1)+b2)
          


        if (a3 < 0):
            opuesto3 = abs(a3)
            multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila1=(opuesto3*a1/a1),(opuesto3*b1/a1),(opuesto3*c1/a1),(opuesto3*d1/a1)
            print(multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila1)
            resta_fila3_con_fila1=((opuesto3*a1/a1)+a3),((opuesto3*b1/a1)+b3),((opuesto3*c1/a1)+c3),((opuesto3*d1/a1)+d3)
            print(resta_fila3_con_fila1)
            div3=((opuesto3*b1/a1)+b3)
        else:
            opuesto4 = a3 * (-1)
            multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila1=(opuesto4*a1/a1),(opuesto4*b1/a1),(opuesto4*c1/a1),(opuesto4*d1/a1)
            print(multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila1)
            resta_fila3_con_fila1=((opuesto4*a1/a1)+a3),((opuesto4*b1/a1)+b3),((opuesto4*c1/a1)+c3),((opuesto4*d1/a1)+d3)      #Aquí condición 1 con fila3  con 2
            print(resta_fila3_con_fila1)
            div4=((opuesto4*b1/a1)+b3)

        numero=div2/div4
        print(numero)
        if (numero < 0):
            opuesto = abs(numero)
            multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila2=(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+a3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+b3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+c3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+d3))
            print(multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila2)
            resta_fila3_con_fila2=((opuesto4*a1/a1)+a3)+((opuesto2*a1/a1)+a2),((opuesto*a3)+b2),((opuesto*a3)+c2),((opuesto*a3)+d2)#Aquí
            print(resta_fila3_con_fila2)
        else:
            opuesto = numero * (-1)
            multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila2=(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+a3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+b3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+c3)),(opuesto*((opuesto4*a1/a1)+d3))
            print(multiplicacion_fila3_con_fila2)
            resta_fila3_con_fila2=((opuesto4*a1/a1)+a3)+((opuesto2*a1/a1)+a2),((opuesto*a3)+b2),((opuesto*a3)+c2),((opuesto*a3)+d2)
            print(resta_fila3_con_fila2)

    else:

        if (a2 < 0):
            opuesto = abs(a2)
            multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1=(opuesto*a1/a1),(opuesto*b1/a1),(opuesto*c1/a1),(opuesto*d1/a1)
            print(multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1)
        else:
            opuesto = a2 * (-1)
            multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1=(opuesto*a1/a1),(opuesto*b1/a1),(opuesto*c1/a1),(opuesto*d1/a1)
            print(multiplicacion_fila2_con_fila1)

    
elif a1 and a3 > a2:
    v2=(a2,b2,c2,d2)
    print(v2)
    if (a2 != 1) and (b2 != 1) and (c2 != 1) and (d2 != 1):
        a1,b1,c1,d1=Fraction(a2/a2),Fraction(b2/a2),Fraction(c2/a2),Fraction(d2/a2)
        
        
        print(f'\n{a1},{b1},{c1},{d1}')

elif a1 and  a2 > a3:
    v3=(a3,b3,c3,d3)
    print(v3)

else:
    print('Todas las matrices son iguales')
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Por cierto, si existe alguna forma de optimizar el código estaré encantado por la ayuda. Agradezco mucho su apoyo, saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con _"un error que no está definido"_? Diría que  los errores siempre están definidos... nunca he visto tal cosa como un error que no está definido. Sugerencia: incluye **siempre** el mensaje de error **exacto** que obtienes.

Comment: ¿Por qué divides el código en dos? ¿son dos archivos distintos?

Comment: Una disculpa, me comí unas palabras por eso la confusión, ya está corregido, quise decir "un error de que una variable no está definida": **NameError: name 'div2' is not defined** El código lo dividí en dos porque era demasiado largo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y dejalo junto, si va junto en tu archivo. Y, como ya dije antes, incluye el mensaje de error **en la pregunta**, no en comentarios.

Comment: Como lo comenté anteriormente, ya está corregido. Saludos!

Comment: Pude ejecutar tu código sin problemas en python 3.7 y 3.9

Comment: Me puedes mostrar una captura de pantalla, por favor? Muchas gracias

Comment: Ok, creo que ya entiendo por qué te sale correctamente, aún no se ha definido las otras condiciones de las otras 2 filas. Trata de ingresar estos números en las filas: f1: 2, 4, 5, 6 | f2: -6, 4, 3, 2 | f3: 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Si, EMHO, ya que el error depende de qué se ingrese, debiste incluir esos valores como parte de la pregunta. Tienes suerte que estoy interesado en mejorar en python, y eso me motivó a ver de que se trataba a pesar de poder reproducirlo. Pero no todos tienen el tiempo, ni la motivación, ni las ganas de leer tanto código como el que has publicado, por eso es mejor reducirlo hasta un [mcve]. Como sea, te dejé una respuesta con mis comentarios.

Comment: Un poco de paciencia mi amigo con los que vamos empezando en python. Yo también quiero mejorar python y para eso antes tengo que preguntar y aprender. De todas formas, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tus respuestas. Salduos!

Comment: Bueno, yo también estoy empezando en python. Además, vaya si he sido paciente... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La variable `div2` la inicializas dentro de un `else`, por tanto estará definida solamente si el código de ese `else` se ejecuta, si ese código no se ejecuta, la variable nunca se define y el error tiene toda la razón de ser.

Simplificando las cosas a un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), prueba el siguiente script, que creo que te lo dejará más claro:

```
respuesta = input("¿quieres error si/no?").lower()

if respuesta=="si":
    otravariable = "no importa, yo existo solo para hacer el ejemplo"
else:
    div2 = 10
    
print('div2:', div2)
print("felicidades, has evitado el error")
```

Si respondes `si` a la pregunta, al momento de utilizar la variable en `print()` sin antes haberla inicializado, se lanzará el error:

```
NameError: name 'div2' is not defined
```

En cambio, si respondes cualquier otra cosa, el *script* se ejecutará hasta el final sin problemas, ya que se inicializa (y por tanto comienza a existir) al ejecutarse el `else`.

¿Lo ves claro ahora? Sinceramente espero que si.

La solución, para tu código, no la sé con exactitud... pero quiero pensar que luego de la explicación y la simplificación, tu mismo sabrás que hacer.

Para ayudarte a encontrar tu solución, yo veo dos caminos:

- La línea que genera el error debe ejecutarse solo bajo las mismas condiciones en las que se crearon las variables que utiliza. Para evitar el error de que `div2` no existe, entonces, podrías poner la condición

  ```
  if not (a2 < 0):
      numero=div2/div4
      print(numero)
      bla, bla, bla
  ```

  He utilizado intencionalmente la construcción `not ()` para mantener las cosas simples copiando la condición del `if` cuyo `else` es el que crea la variable (ya que el código del else se ejecuta solo cuando la condición no es verdadera).

  En el código real, debes poner tanto la condición bajo la que se inicializa `div2` como la condición bajo la que se inicializa `div4`, de otra manera aún veras errores cuando no se ejecute el `else` donde se define `div4`.

  Y claro, ahora podrías tener el *problema* que numero no siempre va a estar definido, si es que se usa más adelante en el algorítmo.
- Otra solución es inicializar ambas variables antes de iniciar con los `if`. Puedes inicializarlas sin valor, esto obliga a que estén definidas:

  ```
  div2 = None
  div4 = None
  numero = None

  if ():
     bla, bla, bla
  ```

  Cuando llegues a la línea donde se utilizan, debes verificar que tengan algún valor, lo cual resulta más simple que replicar todas las condiciones anteriores, ya que se puede evaluar directamente la variable, que está garantizado que si existe, por ejemplo:

  ```
  if (div2) and (div4)
      numero = div2/div4
  ```

Al final, quizás no sea ninguno de estos caminos la solución, pero creo que ya verás el camino con más claridad.